# Angular form validation - form in form

Tags: angularjs

I want to validate two forms. The MAIN form is for e.q. for **Company** model and second form is for **CompanyAddress** model.

`CompanyAddressForm` is inside `CompanyForm`. 
I'm having problems while validating CompanyForm. It depends on `CompanyAddressForm` validation and I don't want that.

```
// Main form
<form ...>
    <input ... required />
    // MODAL
    <button submit ... ng-disabled=MainForm.$invalid>
</form>

// Second form is in modal
<form. ..>
    <input ... />
    <button submit=SecondForm.$invalid />
</form>
```

// And there is problem.

Comment: did you have a name on the 2 forms like this : `<form name="MainForm">` and `<form name="SecondForm">`  ?

Comment: Yes. And in inputs validation same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the html5 spec (and the xhtml spec), it is NOT allowed to have another form inside a form:

*Content model:
Flow content, but with no form element descendants.*
Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

Therefore I strongly (!) suggest you to restructure your forms and not put them into each other, as the behavior may vary (across browsers and over time).

Comment: Ok, thx. I was thinking that is not allowed. So how I can do that validation of inputs inside MODAL that doesn't react with main form?

Comment: The solution won't be perfect when having form elements outside the form, as there are different ways of submitting a form, not just by clicking on the submit button (e.g. "ctrl-enter" in some browsers). If possible, you should avoid this case.

If you really need to do it this way, you need to trigger the validation manually like this:
`angular.forEach(<array-with-all-form-elements>, function(field) { field.$setDirty(); });`

Answer (score 0):

handle both forms seperately using different class or id

You cannot have one form inside another...this is a bad programming pract

Comment: But how I can do that? I set different ID, Name for inputs inside "second" form and still the mainForm says that these inpust are not valid.

Comment: You can do one thing, You can define two different forms and set different controllers for it, So you dont need to define forms inside another form, its a bad practice. Handle the forms separately.